# Why am I having problems reading a  cookie value?

Tags: jquery, cookies

This is my first post on this site expecting one good solution.
I have created a vertical accordian menu HTML structure as given below, What I want is when I click on a sub link of any ul that should be active on page refresh also, Here everything is going well but cookie value I am not getting correctly (Checking it in firebug) and I am using jquery cookie plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Html:

```
<div class="left-nav">
  <h3>Main one</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link">Sub one-1</li>
    <li><a href="link">Sub one-2</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Main Two</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link">Sub two-1</li>
    <li><a href="link">Sub two-2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
if (checkCookie != "") {
  $('.left-nav > ul > li > a:eq('+ checkCookie +')').parent().parent().show();
} else {
  $('.left-nav > ul > li > a:eq('+ 0 +')').parent().parent().show();
}

$('.left-nav > ul > li > a').click(function (){
  var navIndex = $('.left-nav > ul > li > a').index(this);
  $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
  $('.left-nav > ul > li > a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Very little of this code is relevant to getting your cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myCookie = document.cookie;

$("h3").click(function(){
   var myIndex = $(this).index();
   myCookie = "menuActive="+myIndex;
});

//Read which menu its active

var thisCookie = myCookie.split("menuActive=");
var cookieData = thisCookie[1];
var cookieResult = unescape(cookieData);

$("left-nav ul").hide();
$("left-nav ul").eq(cookieResult).show();
```